# Migrate websites from old provider to AWS - One instance per website? - Best Practise

Tags: amazon-web-services, migration

**Information**

1. I'm currently at a german provider with my websites: 1und1.de (past) -> ionos.de (now). I do have 33 Domains, and 23 Websites. 4 of them with wordpress and the rest of them with angular and bootstrap. Currently there are only about 100.000 Pageviews/Month on ALL sites, because many of them are static pages for freelancers (more like a online business card).
2. I also use one website like a manually setup REST API for my apps. I do have 18 apps in the appstores. They whitelisted the domain and do asynchrone requests to "www.domain.de/app1/api/get/avatars/" or "www.domain.de/app2/api/get/players".
3. I want to update all apps and websites to newer technologie (like firebase) so consider that in your answer maybe.
4. I do have unlimited webspace.

**Question**

Recently I registered an AWS account and wondered weather I have to register one instance for each website or if there is an instances, where I could migrate all at once?

Comment: The instance is your canvas: you can organize an instance for each site, an instance for each web server, or put everything in a single instance. Is that the question?

Comment: You can do whatever you want with EWS.

Comment: IMHO best practice is you set up your websites using infrastructure as code, then auto scale a fleet of servers based on load. This gives you scalability, reliability, fault tolerance. Doing this for 23 websites is going to take a LOT of time. The best architecture for you depends on your requirements, your RTO / RPO, your technical skills, etc.

Comment: It might help answer your question if you could indicate what your inclination is - would you prefer to manage a single webserver/host, or several? Do you have any reason to want to run more than one (e.g. isolating some types of content from others, e.g. 'business cards' from API)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For static sites, you should look at [hosting them directly from S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html). That will save you a huge amount of money over creating instances and running actual services on them.

For Wordpress hosting, you can use [Lightsail](https://aws.amazon.com/lightsail/projects/wordpress/)

This is a hugely broad question though. There is certainly no reason you can't just spin up one medium sized EC2 instance, install Apache/Nginx, and just host all the stuff there with an Aurora backend.

Best practice in terms of AWS is all about dynamic scaling and recoverability. The cloud makes the most sense if you're only paying for what you need.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should be taking in mind is how AWS charges you: It will charge space, vCPUs, RAM, I/O, data transfer, and even the air you breathe. So, that said, "unlimited disk space" is out of question.

There is a nice price calculator that gives you some idea of how much AWS will cost you and it's available in [here](https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html).

Now, about how you're gonna install and make these websites available, there are several options. You could choose LightSail, a simpler and more cost-friendly approach, that gives you instances, much alike Digital Ocean, with storage and networking. Another option is to convert your websites to containers and use its container service, which is called ECS, or even implement your own infrastructure (usually, use their own solutions are more cost-effective) and, of course, you could install plain EC2 instances, LAMP stack and run your websites. But there's no need at all to exist a one server/one website relation. If you think about scalability, containers give you a little bit flexibility, but are a little bit more complex at start to work with.

Hope that shines some light on the question.

Best regards.